# Providers Array in app.module.ts in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng-modules

This might just well be a trivial question but I need to clarify the doubts.

I was following the tutorial `https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html` and suddenly it stuck me.

In my **hero.component.js**

I have

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  template:`
            <h2>My Heroes</h2>
            <ul class="heroes">
              <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [class.selected]="hero === hero" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
                <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
              </li>
            </ul>
            <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>`,
  styles: [`
    .selected {
      background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes {
      margin: 0 0 2em 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      width: 15em;
    }
    .heroes li {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #EEE;
      margin: .5em;
      padding: .3em 0;
      height: 1.6em;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .heroes li.selected:hover {
      background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes li:hover {
      color: #607D8B;
      background-color: #DDD;
      left: .1em;
    }
    .heroes .text {
      position: relative;
      top: -3px;
    }
    .heroes .badge {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: small;
      color: white;
      padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
      background-color: #607D8B;
      line-height: 1em;
      position: relative;
      left: -1px;
      top: -4px;
      height: 1.8em;
      margin-right: .8em;
      border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }
  `]

})

export class HeroComponent implements OnInit { 
  selectedHero:Hero ;
  heroes:Hero[];

  constructor(private _heroService:HeroService){} 

  onSelect(hero:Hero): void{
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes():void {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(myHeroes => this.heroes = myHeroes) ;
  }

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.getHeroes();
  }

}
```

This has **errors** which looks like caused by the `missed reference of ./hero.service`

But the file is already part of `app.module.ts Providers Array`.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroComponent }  from './hero.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service'; 

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
                  BrowserModule,
                  FormsModule
                ], 
  declarations: [ 
                  AppComponent,
                  HeroComponent,
                  HeroDetailComponent
                ], 
  providers:    [
                  HeroService 
                ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then why do we need to import `import { HeroService } from './hero.service';` again in `hero.componnet.ts` file **to get rid of the rerrors**?

**Is not @NgModule meant to get rid of repetitive imports of all our directives,components,pipes etc. as pointed out by this blog :**

`https://scotch.io/bar-talk/getting-to-know-angular-2s-module-ngmodule` ?

Comment: I think you are confusing two different things here. The imports in the `@NgModule` declare or provide different components, pipes, services, etc. for others who use this module and components within the module itself. 

The second import, at the top of each component, e.g. `import { UserService } from './user-service';` is like importing the interface description to provide the knowledge to this component on how this service can be used.

Comment: @alexkucksdorf It seems that not importing sevices into the `app.module.ts` and leave the `providers` array blank, just import the service to the `component` and have the instance of the service can make everything works fine. So, why do we have the `providers` array in `module`?

Comment: If you use the `module` approach, you will have *one* instance of your service that will be shared across your components, which means less memory load and easier data sharing between component. Otherwise each requesting component will have its own instance of the service.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  providers : [HeroService],
  template:`
            <h2>My Heroes</h2>
            <ul class="heroes">
              <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [class.selected]="hero === hero" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
                <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
              </li>
            </ul>
            <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>`,
  styles: [`
    .selected {
      background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes {
      margin: 0 0 2em 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      width: 15em;
    }
    .heroes li {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #EEE;
      margin: .5em;
      padding: .3em 0;
      height: 1.6em;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .heroes li.selected:hover {
      background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes li:hover {
      color: #607D8B;
      background-color: #DDD;
      left: .1em;
    }
    .heroes .text {
      position: relative;
      top: -3px;
    }
    .heroes .badge {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: small;
      color: white;
      padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
      background-color: #607D8B;
      line-height: 1em;
      position: relative;
      left: -1px;
      top: -4px;
      height: 1.8em;
      margin-right: .8em;
      border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }
  `]

})

export class HeroComponent implements OnInit { 
  selectedHero:Hero ;
  heroes:Hero[];

  constructor(private _heroService:HeroService){} 

  onSelect(hero:Hero): void{
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes():void {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(myHeroes => this.heroes = myHeroes) ;
  }

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.getHeroes();
  }

}
```